# CSS Positioning Breaks Hyperlinks in Lists

Tags: html, css, mootools, joomla1.5

I am working on a Joomla1.5 website.

I have two navigation menus in the left column using ULs inside DIVs.

When I float my DIVs, my hyperlinks will not mouseover. Turning of CSS in Firefox fixes it.

Note: could this be MooTools interfering?

```
<div id="left">

    <div class="moduletable intro"> 
                <h1><img src="/images/stories/pastarchives.jpg" border="0" /></h1>

<h1>A modern-day, holiday apartment in the heart of Tuscany</h1>        </div> 
            <div class="moduletable _menu_property"> 
                    <ul class="menu"><li id="current" class="active item1"><a href="http://petruzzo.mikeritter.aghosted.com/"><span>Home</span></a></li><li class="item4"><a href="/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=2&amp;Itemid=4"><span>Floor Plan</span></a></li><li class="item5"><a href="/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=3&amp;Itemid=5"><span>Location</span></a></li><li class="item8"><a href="/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=7&amp;Itemid=8"><span>Contact</span></a></li></ul>     </div> 
            <div class="moduletable _menu_reservations"> 
                    <ul class="menu"><li class="item14"><a href="/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=4&amp;Itemid=14"><span>Rates and Prices</span></a></li><li class="item12"><a href="/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=5&amp;Itemid=12"><span>Special Offers</span></a></li><li class="item13"><a href="/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=1&amp;Itemid=13"><span>Availability</span></a></li><li class="item11"><a href="/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=6&amp;Itemid=11"><span>Book Now</span></a></li></ul>        </div> 
            <div class="moduletable"> 
                    <ul class="menu"><li class="item15"><a href="/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=category&amp;layout=blog&amp;id=2&amp;Itemid=15"><span>Marti Blog</span></a></li></ul>      </div> 


</div>
```

---

CSS

---

```
div._menu_property,div._menu_reservations{width:160px; margin:0px; margin-left:; margin-right:; float:left;}

div._menu_property ul li span,div._menu_reservations ul li span{display:block;}

div._menu_property a,div._menu_reservations a{display:block;}

.article_column {width:300px; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; float:left;}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `overflow:hidden` on the div? Could you post a code sample (HTML+CSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `float:left` on your last `.moduletable`

(other `.moduletable` which are `div._menu_property, div._menu_reservations` do have a float:left but not your last `.moduletable`)

Comment: This got me on the right track! I had to set the last .moduletable to clear:both

Comment: FYI - you should add a module class suffix to the final menu module, otherwise any you apply to .moduletable will be inherited by all modules divs.